# ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.get(view) always returns null

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have a compound view that I want to create its viewmodel by `ViewModelLazy`, I need to send the `ViewModelStoreOwner` of the view to `ViewModelLazy` but trying to get the `ViewModelStoreOwner` using `ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.get(this)` always returns null. The compound view itself is a simple view, but I am using it in a recyclerview adapter that resides in a fragment. Right now, I am getting forced to use the parent fragment `ViewModelStoreOwner`, which is causing all the items in the adapter to have the same viewmodel instance. I searched for an example on how to use `ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner` but I can't find one, am I missing something?

Note: I am injecting the viewmodel by dagger-hilt

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how it can be implemented in custom view.

```
class SummaryView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

  private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()!!).get<SummaryViewModel>()
  }

  override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    viewModel.summaryModel.observe(findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()!!, ::populateSummaryView)
  }

  private fun populateSummaryView(summaryModel: SummaryModel) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Found this great example [here](https://www.sasikanth.dev/using-viewmodels-in-custom-views/)

Comment: For further explanation, `findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()` must be called after the view has been attached to the window as shown in the example

Comment: This is throwing null pointer exception when i am using this view inside a compose view - with jetpack compose, any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

1, you need update

```
androidx.activity to 1.2.0
androidx.fragment to 1.3.0
```

2, activity or fragment set its ViewModelStore to rootViw via setTag, so any view in activity or fragment's rootView gets the same ViewModelStoreOwner and also same ViewModelStore.

```
// ComponentActivity line 409
ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(getWindow().getDecorView(), this) 
// ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner line 50
view.setTag(R.id.view_tree_view_model_store_owner, viewModelStoreOwner);
```